# Where do I keep the relevant jars so that I am able to use them when I have deployed the application?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jakarta-ee, web-applications

How do I use external library while developing applications on google app engine ? Suppose I have to use `javax.mail` library. Where do I keep the llibrary so that when I deploy the application on the server,I am able to use the relevant jars ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
WEB-INF/lib
```

This applies to servlets in general, not just Google App Engine.  The one caveat you have to keep in mind is Google App Engine controls which version of JDK they use.  This means if the library you're using has any dependencies on 1.7 or relies on code deprecated in 1.5 or 1.6 then it won't work.

There is a list of libraries tested on App Engine, as [koma](https://stackoverflow.com/users/820142/koma) pointed out.  It can be found here:

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/jrewhitelist

Since you're using a library not on that list, you have no guarantee it will work on app engine.  You'll just have to give it a shot and see.

Comment: but javax.mail happens to be a very bad example, as it is not whitelisted : https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/jrewhitelist

Comment: Good point.  I haven't done much development on app engine in a while, but there was more than one library I had to just upload and see if it worked for myself.  At any rate, I've updated my answer to address your comment.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Maven, you could look into creating a super jar (a jar that contains all your binary files and any referenced jars).

Sorry I can't provide specific instructions, I have not done this with Maven directly but only through leiningen.